# Remove Red Under Line In Visual Studio Code Show Error In Php

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Visual studio code** show syntax error in Codeigniter 3 how to fix them...

[image]

How to i remove these under line in visual studio code

Comment: What does it say when you hover it?

Comment: You might need to install some specific VSCode extension for codeigniter to sort that out. Something like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=small.php-ci (don't know the quality of that one. Just the first I found). The issue is how libraries etc are loaded in codeigniter, and how you access them. Those properties aren't actual hard coded properties in the class, but rather dynamic accessed using magic methods etc, which makes it impossible for PHP to figure out that they exist on it's own.

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me in PHP Codeigniter too, It's a Intelephense thing.
You can disable Intelephense undefined property in Settings > Extensions > intelephense > Undefined property

[image]

But i think the best way to handle it is, add on top of document the property definition, to tell intelephense what is this property. Example:

For `$this->data_session = $this->session->userdata();`

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there disadvantages if I disable the Diagnostics: Undefined Properties?

Comment: I haven't noticed anything, I've had that configuration since I wrote that post and I haven't had any problems. Its true that i use some codeigniter extensions..

Answer (score 3):

just add the below line above your

```
/**
 *  @property YourClassName $YourObjectName 
 */
```

[image: For Form validation]

[image: ModelClassName]

Answer (score 0):

It's for PHP Intelephense version, the current version has some configuration that mark framework's code, just go back to old version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).